# function does not work when i'm trying to check are borders same

Tags: jquery

I made the system that checks is username available and if not it makes "username" input's border 1px solid red but if it available changes to 1px solid green. It works! I also did the same thing with e-mail and passwords match and other...But i also want to check have users corrected their mistakes when they click submit button. So i made a function

```
function checkRegisterErrors() {
    if( $('#register_username').css('border')=='1px solid red') {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

but it does not work. i also added an attribute "onclick" on my submit and checked...if I just change my function content to alert(); it works fine when i click on button.

Comment: Colours, in JavaScript, tend to be returned in - in many browsers, if not all - in `rgb()`, or `rgba()`, format rather than simply returning the value that was set in the CSS. Using class-names is much more reliable.

Comment: Did you do any basic debugging when it doesn't work?  Put a `console.log()` statement in the function to see that it gets called and to see what the `.css()` actually is?  This should the basics of troubleshooting yourself.

Comment: You are returning `false`, but not `true`.  Is there more to your function?

Comment: i'm returning false because i don't want that users can send their data when they did not correct their mistakes :) okay i will try to make it with classes :) thank you a lot :)

Comment: if you are doing validation based on css border values you are **doing it not just wrong but way wrong**

Comment: I'm doing it with borders and then check it with php.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use a class to know if an element is on a state or another one. Is a much reliable practice than to read css properties.

Like

```
.selected{
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

And then in the HTML

```
<input id="name" class="selected" />
```

and in the javascript:

```
if( $("#name").hasClass("selected")){
    ... do something;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. @Danielius remember to choose the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can check css styles for perform the validation its much unreliable method since you are checking for strings and css styles have different variants across browser. More reliable method is to use a class, a view-model or data- attributes to determine the validity of your fields.

```
var model = {
  username:'',
  usernameAvailable: false
};

$('#myusernameinput').on('change', function(){
   if(checkUserNameIsAvailable()){
     model.usernameAvailable = true;
   }
   else{
     model.usernameAvailable = false;
   }
});
```

then

```
function checkRegisterErrors() {
  if(!model.usernameAvailable) {
    return false;
  } 
}
```

or you can use data- attributes.

```
$('#myusernameinput').on('change', function(){
  if(checkUserNameIsAvailable()){
     $(this).attr('data-userNameAvailable', 'false');
  }
  else{
    $(this).attr('data-userNameAvailable', 'true');
  }
});
```

then

```
function checkRegisterErrors() {
   if($('#register_username').attr('data-userNameAvailable')== 'false') {
      return false;
   } 
}
```